# For which values of $a$ is $f_a(x)=x^a$ for $x>0$ and $0$ otherwise continuous, differentiable, and twice differentiable at zero?

Tags: real-analysis

This is similar to a pre-existing question, but with one difference.

Let $f_a(x)=x^a$ if $x>0$, and $f_a(x)=0$ if $x\leq0$.

For which values of $a$ is $f(x)$ continuous at zero? I think it's $a>0$.

For which values of $a$ is $f(x)$ differentiable at zero? I think it's $a>1$.

For which values of $a$ is $f(x)$ twice differentiable at zero (f'(x) exists and is differentiable)? I say $a>2$.

I'm not sure about these answers, please tell me if I'm wrong, and if so, how to correct it.

Comment: Give some reasons for your answers, not just what you think the answer is.